# How to Pass Ansible Variables to PowerShell script?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, ansible

This is my PS script

```
#Map the client cert to the User
param
(
    # Parameter help description
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$username
)

New-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\ClientCertificate `
    -Subject "$username@localhost" `
    -URI * `
    -Issuer D2D38EE665F0AE3C106367EFB `
    -Credential H123Ansible `
    -Force
```

This is my Ansible Task

```
- name: PS script to configure WinRM Certificate Authentication
  ansible.windows.win_shell: "C:\\Temp\\cert_based_winrm_auth.ps1 -username {{ username }}"
```

I have tried different ways of running the script (", ', args, curly bracket, without curly brackets, $username, =$username) but nothing worked. I gave searched lot to find a solution that matches my problem. But no luck.

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong and how to correct it?
Is there any other way it can be done? like running the PS script in the ansible instead of ps file.

Advanced Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please mind that [`... nothing worked` is not an accurate description of the problem you're facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). You should read [ask] paying a particular attention to the [mre] section. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the `win_powershell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html) instead:

```
- name: PS script to configure WinRM Certificate Authentication
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      [CmdletBinding()]
      param (
          [String]
          $Username
      )

      C:\Temp\cert_based_winrm_auth.ps1 -username $Username
    parameters:
      Username: {{ username }}
```